# I made a Cycle Animation with F-Modifier, but how can i stop it in a exact frame?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I made an animation with F-Modifier on the Graph Editor and it's working, starts from 0 to the infinite...but if i need to make it stops at for example frame 200, how can i do that?

Comment: do you want stop the modifier or freeze the animation?

Comment: Freeze the animation just in the frame 200

Comment: did you try the " Restrict Frame Range " in the modifier ?

Comment: Nope, i don't know about that option...where do i activate it?

Comment: at the bottom of the F-modifier

Comment: @beavarou or you can choose the Limit modifier to clip  the whole animation

Answer (score 1):

if you want to limit the whole **animation** use the **limit** modifier :

[image]

and to limit one **modifier** only use the **Restrict Frame Range** option :

[image]

Comment: @beavoru check this [file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34514)